# recvfrom - How to convert buffer to string

Tags: c

I'm currently learning the network programming with C/C++... I have experience .NET but not in C (esp: in Unix network programming)

The problem that I'm facing right now is that when I receive the message, I like to split it into two parts. The format of message will be like `[command] filepath` (For example: `get a.txt` or `put a.txt`)

I'm using recvform to receive the message.

```
int recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, int len, unsigned int flags,
             struct sockaddr *from, int *fromlen);
```

The problem is that I dont know how to convert "void *buff" into string so that I can do String.Split(" ") to get the command and file name.

Could anyone please explain me a way to convert "void *buff" to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually pass the pointer to the start of a character array as the buffer.  The `recvfrom()` system call writes into that array.  You then process the array as a character string - after ensuring that it is properly null terminated (which `recvfrom()` will not do).  Of course, the sending end has to put the data on in a compatible format, but the `recvfrom()` will give you what the sender sent you.

So, the direct answer is "You don't convert the `void *` into a character string; you convert the character string into a `void *` by passing it to `recvfrom()`".

Comment: Thanks.  You mean, something like that below?? 


char* message = "get a.txt";

returnStatus = sendto(sockd, message, strlen(argv[3])+1, 0,
      (struct sockaddr *)&xferServer, sizeof(xferServer));

Comment: @Michael: yes - more or less...If you send it like that, adjusting the strlen() to apply to message instead of argv[3], you include the trailing NUL because of the +1 and then the recvfrom() would have a null terminated string incoming.

Answer (score 1):

You will want a character buffer and the size of the buffer. Like this:

```
char buf[1024];
const size_t buf_len = sizeof(buf);
```

Then you can call recvfrom like so:

```
ssize_t r;
r = recvfrom(sock, buf, buf_len-1, flags, &sock_from, &sock_from_len);
if(r<0) {
  handle_error(r);
} else if(r == 0) {
  handle_closed_socket(sock);
} else {
  buf[r] = '\0';
}
```

The `buf[r] = '\0';` will guarantee that your buffer is a proper null-terminated C string. Then you can pass `buf` around as a string.

Answer (score 0):

C is not C++. There's no string class. The strtok function might help you get what you want, assuming you null terminate your buffer manually.